# How to split String with ||

Tags: java, string, split

When I split a String:

> "EMP ID||EMP NAME||DESIGNATION"

I get each letter split:

> [, E, M, P,  , I, D, |, |, E, M, P,  , N, A,
>   M, E, |, |, D, E, S, I, G, N, A, T, I, O, N]

My code is

```
String strHeader="EMP ID||EMP NAME||DESIGNATION";
String[] arrStrColumnsInRow=strHeader.split("||");
```

How can I get it splitted like:

> [EMP ID,EMP NAME,DESIGNATION]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use

```
String[] arrStrColumnsInRow=strHeader.split("\\|\\|");
```

This is because the parameter of [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) is a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum), where `|` is a logical operator.

Answer (score 5):

`|` is special for regular expressions - you need to escape them:

```
String strHeader = "EMP ID||EMP NAME||DESIGNATION";
String[] arrStrColumnsInRow = strHeader.split("\\|\\|");
System.err.println(Arrays.toString(arrStrColumnsInRow));
```

Output:

```
[EMP ID, EMP NAME, DESIGNATION]
```